# Try for x seconds, then leave?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to write in C++ try,catch statement with timer in that way that if function is not able to be executed (it's stuck) program just continues?

Comment: You'll probably have to kick off a separate thread to do the work and monitor that thread.

Comment: Can you provide minimal code example. I am not able to get how a program can stuck due to `try/catch` ?

Comment: You'd be better off narrowing it down to the part of the program that can block and replace that with a non-blocking version, if you really mean "getting stuck" rather than just "taking a long but deterministic time".

Comment: What does try/catch have to do with code being stuck?  Do you want an exception to be thrown if the code takes too long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could do this with, for example, [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html).

Look especially at the [timed_join](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.timed_join) function.

Answer (score 0):

The most robust approach is to perform the work in a sub-process, wait for the sub-process with a timeout, then kill it.

Answer (score 0):

KISS:

```
clock_t start = clock();
const int max_try_clocks = 5 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // 5 is the number of seconds 
                                               // we should keep trying for
try_again:
  try {
    // whatever you need to try
  } catch (...) {
    if (clock() - start < max_try_clocks)
      goto try_again;
  }
```